# How can I make adaptive-images send the correct file size for the responsive BootStrap images?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, pagespeed, adaptive-design

I have Matt Willcox's great [adaptive-images](https://github.com/MattWilcox/Adaptive-Images/) working on my site. It works like this:

- Server delivers 800px image.
- Adaptive-images redirects to an image that is no bigger than your resolution width

The problem is that BootStrap displays the images in columns for desktop and full-width for tablet and mobile. So technically, adaptive should be delivering smaller images for desktop than the smaller viewports. Google PageSpeed is slamming me for this. I have 800px images scaling down to about 150px or so.

I've done a lot of research but can't seem to find a workable solution. Should I hack adaptive-images to look at a feature other than resolution width to deliver the correct image? Is there a different library that addresses this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As resolution in cookies is set via JS, you can try to override code that is provided in [installation step 3](http://adaptive-images.com/details.htm#install)

Cookies should have higher priority according to this:

> It handles cases where there isn't a cookie set; mobile devices will be supplied the smallest image, and desktop devices will get the largest

EDIT Also I recommend to pay attention for  tag as it is [described on the projects github page](https://github.com/MattWilcox/Adaptive-Images/#project-status) However, there are still [problems](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture) with browser support for this features, hope they will be fixed in the nearest future

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a S3 bucket to load your images then you can try AWS lambdas to handle your resizing work. You can refer to below article
https://medium.com/@vinay.humberi/image-compression-and-optimisation-with-aws-lambda-deb766fac2fe

Or if you dont want to use amazon services then there is super cheap saas application available called gumlet
https://www.gumlet.com/

Check it out! hope this helps you.